# While loop isn't outputting the correct data

Tags: python, loops, csv, while-loop

So I made corrections to my code as you all suggested. I'm able to get into the loop however once I input a correct name I'm still not able to get out of it. Any suggestions?
Here's what I got:

```
import csv

full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()

with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
    hour_summation = {}
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in read_csv:
        while (' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() != full_name.strip().lower():
            print('Name is not in system')
            full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
        if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
            hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))
print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
```

Here's the result when I give an input:
fyi. Steve Miller is not in the csv file so that first response is correct. However, Sri Mantri is in the file and it should continue on and print out all the listings under her name.

```
Enter your full name: Steve Miller
Name is not in system
Enter your full name: Sri Mantri
Name is not in system
```

Here's what the output should look like when the code runs.

```
Enter your full name: Sri mantri
This is sri mantri full hours report:
Beeline Blank: 28 hours
SRV-0001 Service Requests for Base and Direct Services: 4 hours
SUP-0001 Support Requests with a CISM Ticket: 129 hours
SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support: 72 hours
0026184229 Margin Controlling Java Rewrite: 4 hours
0033472751 PRE-AFE 2017 - CMS Enhancements: 2 hours
0033472863 PRE-AFE 2017 - BPM Enhancements: 67 hours
APP-10008 Pre-Series (Non-Mainframe): 4 hours
APP-10146 Logistics (Non-Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10195 Vehicle Labor System (Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10354 Web PartsPro (Non-Mainframe): 1 hours
APP-10431 VIPService (Non-Mainframe): 1 hours
APP-10432 VIPService (Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10536 Truck Invoice Adjustments (Mainframe): 2 hours
```

and the csv looks like this:

```
   First Name   Last Name   Activity    Hours
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  11
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  3
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  5
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  2
Jeff    Moore   SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  3
David   Ayers   SUP-2507  NAFTA MFTS OS Support 10
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    4
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    3
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    1
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
In this case, please provide the data file and hard-code a name as the search target.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables and you will see if they different or not .

Comment: why do you use `name` to get second `input()` and you check `full_name` ? you should use only `full_name`.

Comment: NEVER change question - now our answers doesn't fit to your problem. If you have new problem then create new question with button `Add Question`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP changed text and now it is different problem. It doesn't fit to existing answers.

Comment: My mistake. I'll make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Inside this code you use `name` to get name but later you use `full_name`

```
 while (' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() != full_name.strip():
        print('Name is not in system')
        name = input('Enter your full name: ')
```

You should use only `full_name` (and it needs `lower()`)

```
 while (' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() != full_name.strip():
        print('Name is not in system')
        full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower() # <-- full_name
```

Or convert `name` to `full_name`

```
 while (' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() != full_name.strip():
        print('Name is not in system')
        name = input('Enter your full name: ')
        full_name = name.lower() # <-- full_name
```

Comment: Take a look at the changes I made below.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a line in your while loop that connects name to full_name:

```
full_name = name.lower()
```

Add this in your while loop, just below the input() call, like you have towards the top of your file.

Inside your `while` loop, it should say:

```
name = input('Enter your full name: ')
full_name = name.lower()
```

That will get your program to run, further, at least!

Also, please note that the logic of your program is probably flawed... You step through each line of the CSV, checking for a person's name. That means that if you have more than one entry in the CSV file, (i.e. - the CSV file holds more than just one person's info), you're only really able to access the first in the list.  You should probably prompt for a username, THEN run through each row of the CSV to check for a match.  Only if there is no match in the entire CSV should you ask for another name... Just give it a look...

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually interested in other solutions go for my answer else just skip it. With pandas it is more easier to solve your need.

So I have a CSV file("names.csv") with this values in it,

```
Name    Hours
Sri Mati    1
Some Name   2
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv = pandas.read_csv("names.csv")
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if (csv["Name"]==name).any():
        print("Name Present")
        correct_name = csv.loc[csv["Name"] == name]
        # print everything
        print(csv)
        print()
        #print correct name
        print(correct_name)
        print() # for clear display
        # get individual things
        print("Correct Inidividual Values")
        print(correct_name.values)
    else:
        print("Name not there")
```

**Sample Input and Output:**

```
Enter your name: Steve Miller
Name not there
```

Next run,

```
Enter your name: Sri Mati
Name Present
        Name  Hours
0   Sri Mati      1
1  Some Name      2

       Name  Hours
0  Sri Mati      1

Correct Inidividual Values
[['Sri Mati' 1]]
```